# Failure to allocate memory resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm developing this test application in C++ and OpenCL but I just CAN'T figure out why I am getting this very weird problem which further results in segmentation fault.

Some of the code:

```
output = new cl_float[TestCount*TrainCount]; // output array
output_buf = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float)*TestCount*TrainCount, NULL);
// .... some more stuff
queue->enqueueReadBuffer(*output_buf, CL_TRUE, 0, TestCount*TrainCount, output);
```

Here, output and output_buf are pointers to their respective data.

The seg-fault occurs when I try to access any element of the output array after everything has been processed. Upon further debugging, I found that the maximum number of elements it is storing is 562 whereas it should be 2250 (TestCount=150, TrainCount=15). Moreover, the surprising thing is that I can access any element from GDB but not 562 upwards.

I have no doubt that there is no error in the code and I'm absolutely sure that all the 2250 outputs are being processed by the GPU. This was testing by atomically incrementing the first element of the output array in each thread and then outputting it via GDB.

Seems like I have ruled out a lot of possibilities but for the heck of it I still can't figure out what's causing this problem. There is a minuscule chance that the heap is getting filled but I top'ed and found that my application only uses like 37M of memory.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** James is right. It was because of not reading enough bytes from the memory. The backtrace of the seg-fault is as follows-

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000000c
0x0000000100002402 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fff5fbffb88)
    at TestApplication.cpp:202
202     cout << OpenCL_KNN::output[0] << " " << OpenCL_KNN::output[1] << " " << OpenCL_KNN::output[2] << " " << OpenCL_KNN::output[3];
```

The 4 indices being accessed are definitely defined. Nothing before this lines gives me any error. The output array isn't altered/created anywhere other than what I mentioned previously.

**Update 2**: The error is resolved. It was only occurring in Mac OS X. It had something to do what the way I was accessing the output. Once I created a function in OpenCL_KNN namespace returning me the output, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Could someone explain the -ve rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the C++ wrapper for CL, but I'm guessing that `TestCount*TrainCount` is a factor of `sizeof(cl_float)` too few bytes to be reading back from the GPU.  Your code should be:

```
queue->enqueueReadBuffer(*output_buf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*TestCount*TrainCount, output);
```

That doesn't explain your segfault, however.  Perhaps you are making the same error elsewhere?

Comment: Your fix has got me access to all the elements of the array. I can't believe I overlooked such a simple mistake. I've updated the answer with more details.

Comment: I mean details about the seg-fault.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occuring because you are accessing the memory either not initialized or being deleted.
The error is in this line of code.

```
queue->enqueueReadBuffer(*output_buf, CL_TRUE, 0, TestCount*TrainCount, output);
```

check whether every object and varable(pointer) in you code is initialized properly.Once that is done this error will be gone.It's not necessary that the error has to be generated on the indicated line of code it can occur the position where you access an uninitialized memory address.

Comment: output and output_buf have definitely been initialized as mentioned in the post. I wouldn't be able to run any commands without a faulty queue so that is definitely good as well.

Comment: some times your code is compiled properly. But when you run it at some point, it gives you error.You also mentioned in update "It was because of not reading enough bytes from the memory." that explains my point of uninitialzation

Comment: By faulty queue and not running commands, I mean not able to enqueue any kernel which is NOT the case since I can get output. All the bytes are being read properly now but I still don't know what's causing the seg-fault. The seg-fault is not originating from this line but from where I access the array.

Comment: I told you it occurs by accessing unitialized memory.Lets say You made a dynamically allocated array of 10 positions and lets say you access the 11 position by mistake, it will generate this error.

Comment: I totally understand what you mean and thank you for your input but I am not accessing the output array anywhere in the code other than the line which gives segfault and that too defined indices. What do you think problem in this case could be?